# Apache Poi Format or extension is not valid and file in use locked for editing by another user

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, fileoutputstream

I am using Apache Poi to create an Excel file for my project, but I met a few weird issues while trying it.

```
public void createfile(Request request, Response response) throws Exception {
try {
        Integer id = ParamUtils.getParamInt(request, "id", null);
        Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("new sheet");
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xls");
        workbook.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
        }
        catch (IncorrectData e) {
            return e;
        }

    }
```

Firstly, I got a **format or extension that is not valid** error when I try to open the file I create with this function. Secondly, I got **file in use locked for editing by another user** but I clearly closed OutputStream at the end of the code.
One last question, it was a function at my server and I was wondering if I can pass/return this Excel file to the front to download it?

Thanks!

Comment: You haven't closed the Workbook… it hat a `.close()` method, too, and you can `flush()` the `FileOutputStream` in addition.

Comment: Check your `Workbook` implementation, and use the appropriate file extension.