# Apache poi Java Excel - file is open in Java(TM) Platform SE binary

Tags: java, excel, file-io, apache-poi

I recently worked on my project which needs to use java to write excel files. I choose Apache poi and followed the example online, but seems like there was an issue with the close method for the FileOutputStream.

```
        Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("new sheet");
        Row row = sheet.createRow(1);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(1);
        cell.setCellValue("test");
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xls");
        workbook.write(fileOut);
        workbook.close();
        fileOut.flush();
        fileOut.close();
```

When I click the Excel generate by this code, it says the file extension does not match the file type, also the file can only open in read-only because it was opened in Java(TM) Platform SE binary, but I clearly close the workbook and fileout at the end, I do not know where is the problem with this simple code. I also notice the file I got the size is 0.

Update: Not able to write data into Excel. Tried either xls with HSSFWorkbook or xlsx with XSSFWorkbook, when I open the file it always said the file extension does not match with file format/type, and the data was all lost. If I open it anyway, it was an empty sheet and if I tried to save as, it defines the file as Text(Tab delimited), but I clearly declare it as the Workbook type, not String.

Able to open the file in edit mode, and also able to see the data written in Excel, right now excel is empty and the data did not write into it.

Comment: "_the example online_" - I don't know what example you are looking at, but I would look at the examples [here, for writing a new file](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#NewWorkbook), and also [here for reading an existing file](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#ReadWriteWorkbook). (Note the differences between handling `.xls` formats and `.xlsx` formats.)

Comment: More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76078315/apache-poi-format-or-extension-is-not-valid-and-file-in-use-locked-for-editing-b#comment134172637_76078315).

Comment: "I also notice the file I got the size is 0.": To what file do you think `new FileOutputStream("workbook.xls")` creates a file output stream to? There is no path. So the `workbook.xls` will be located in the directory from which the java virtual machine was started from. Give it a concrete directory path.

Comment: Not able to write data into Excel. Tried either xls with HSSFWorkbook or xlsx with XSSFWorkbook, when I open the file it always said the file extension does not match with file format/type, and the data was all lost. If I open it anyway, it was an empty sheet and if I tried to save as, it defines the file as Text(Tab delimited), but I clearly declare it as the Workbook type, not String.

Comment: I am unable to recreate the problem you describe (and, anyway, what you describe in your update appears to be some different code not shown in the question).

Comment: Provide a complete, self-contained example we can copy and paste and run, without needing to make any changes - in other words, a [mre]. Use a single class, containing only a `main` method, and all the relevant `import` statements. Clarify what version of POI you are using - and which specific POI libraries. Clarify what version of Java, also.

Comment: Finally, I found the problem... it was the issue of missing the dependency common-io... so it fail to write the file...

Comment: Glad you solved it. However... That means you are potentially **missing other dependencies** as well - which may cause more unexpected problems. If you are not using a dependency management tool such as Maven or Gradle, now would be a good time to start.

Comment: I had Maven in my project... but it only works after I insert dependency common-io then maven installs and compile...

Comment: In that case something may be wrong with your Maven POM. POI has a dependency on `commons-io` - and [various other libraries](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/5.2.3). Maven should download them all automatically, without you needing to explicitly include any of them in your POM (except for POI itself).